# displaying drawing on window/console Ruby+Cairo

Tags: ruby, cairo

I'm starting to work on a college project (for Computer Graphics) .... I wanted a library that could do 2d drawings and I came across Cairo. But the thing is, there arent many samples/tutorials/programs on ruby and cairo. Every program i came across, saved an image onto a file.

Can anyone please tell me a way to display these drawings on a window (or a console)??

... and since I'm at the beginning of my project, I wouldn't mind looking into any other alternative library if you can suggest any.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/cairographicstutorial/ (and http://zetcode.com/tutorials/rubygtktutorial/cairo/ for Ruby) which shows how to draw basic shapes, line drawings and text on a Cairo surface within a GTK program.